# How to read different measures from files into and save?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have few csv files that all of the has the following information:

[image]

I need to take each row from every CSV files and add as a row in each different Label separately to be able to take the mean of all measures among all CSV files. I wrote the following lines, but I do not know how to write in an efficient and clean way. defining 6 different `numpy` arrays and then adding each row of `csv` to them separately does not seem a smart way of writing code. what do you suggest? Thanks

```
for filename in csv_files:
     print 'reading CSV file '+ filename
     file_path=join(csv_dir, filename)
     csv = np.genfromtxt (file_path, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: I'd prefer your data not to be displayed as an image.
What you MIGHT want to do is read all files and add each numpy array to a list. Then stack the arrays from the list (e.g. np.hstack) and do operations on the big array.

Comment: @jochen thanks a lot it works for me, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment:
Read each file into a numpy.ndarray and store them into a list. Afterwards stack them together, e.g with np.hstack(arraylist).